# How to call a database root from other Swift file?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm doing an app which have a second auth level, which every time I search on database this code, I go to a `ViewController` which displays all the user data per each code.

```Json
{
  "SchedaVolontari" : {
    "V2016040517" : {
      "CodiceVolontario" : "V2016040517",
      "Cognome" : "SANTORO",
      "DataFineServizio" : "09/01/2018",
      "DataInizioServizio" : "10/01/2017",
      "Form  Mod  1" : "OK",
      "Form  Mod  2" : "OK",
      "Form  Mod  3" : "OK",
      "Form  Mod  4" : "nil",
      "Form  Mod  5" : "nil",
      "Malattie" : 0,
      "Mon  Fin " : "nil",
      "Mon  Iniz " : "OK",
      "Mon  Int " : "nil",
      "Nome" : "SIMONA",
      "Permessi" : 15,
      "Sede" : "Universita' degli Studi di Napoli Federico II - Centro Sinapsi",
      "Titolo" : "Sostegno ed inclusione - Unina Orientale - 2015"
    },
    "V2016040518" : {
      "CodiceVolontario" : "V2016040518",
      "Cognome" : "CUSUMANO",
      "DataFineServizio" : "09/01/2018",
      "DataInizioServizio" : "10/01/2017",
      "Form  Mod  1" : "OK",
      "Form  Mod  2" : "OK",
      "Form  Mod  3" : "OK",
      "Form  Mod  4" : "OK",
      "Form  Mod  5" : "",
      "Malattie" : 0,
      "Mon  Fin " : "",
      "Mon  Iniz " : "",
      "Mon  Int " : "",
      "Nome" : "GIULIA",
      "Permessi" : 4,
      "Sede" : "Universita' degli Studi di Napoli Federico II - Centro Sinapsi",
      "Titolo" : "Sostegno ed inclusione - Unina Orientale - 2015"
    },
    "V2016040520" : {
      "CodiceVolontario" : "V2016040520",
      "Cognome" : "SERIO",
      "DataFineServizio" : "09/01/2018",
      "DataInizioServizio" : "10/01/2017",
      "Form  Mod  1" : "OK",
      "Form  Mod  2" : "OK",
      "Form  Mod  3" : "OK",
      "Form  Mod  4" : "OK",
      "Form  Mod  5" : "OK",
      "Malattie" : 1,
      "Mon  Fin " : "",
      "Mon  Iniz " : "",
      "Mon  Int " : "",
      "Nome" : "FLAVIA",
      "Permessi" : 3,
      "Sede" : "Universita' degli Studi di Napoli Federico II - Centro Sinapsi",
      "Titolo" : "Sostegno ed inclusione - Unina Orientale - 2015"
    },
    "V2016040521" : {
      "CodiceVolontario" : "V2016040521",
      "Cognome" : "LOMBARDI",
      "DataFineServizio" : "09/01/2018",
      "DataInizioServizio" : "10/01/2017",
      "Form  Mod  1" : "OK",
      "Form  Mod  2" : "OK",
      "Form  Mod  3" : "OK",
      "Form  Mod  4" : "OK",
      "Form  Mod  5" : "OK",
      "Malattie" : 0,
      "Mon  Fin " : "",
      "Mon  Iniz " : "",
      "Mon  Int " : "",
      "Nome" : "FABIO",
      "Permessi" : 2,
      "Sede" : "Universita' degli Studi di Napoli Federico II - Centro Sinapsi",
      "Titolo" : "Sostegno ed inclusione - Unina Orientale - 2015"
    },
     //..... and so on... the database is so long that i couldn't write all cases, but i given the idea.
  }
}
```

In the first Swift file I search by child `SchedaVolontari` which user we are talking about.
Once the user insert the validate code, this will perform a segue to another `ViewController`.
Now, the second Swift file have to load the current child that we are talking about. I tried this way, but it doesn't work:

This is the first swift file

```
//
//  AccessoTerzoLivello
//  Amesci
//
//  Created by Gianluca Caliendo on 2017-01-31.
//  Copyright © 2017 Gianluca Caliendo. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase

class AccessoTerzoLivello: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var codvolontario: UITextField!



    @IBAction func accessoSchedaVolontari(_ sender: UIButton) {


        let rootRef = Database.database().reference()

        let conditionalRef = rootRef.child("SchedaVolontari")
    conditionalRef.observe(.value) {(snap: DataSnapshot) in

        // This is empty array which will contain all the codes
        let codesArray: NSMutableArray = []
        // Get all the children from snapshot you got back from Firebase
        let snapshotChildren = snap.children

        // Loop over all children (code) in Firebase
        while let child = snapshotChildren.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
            // Get code node key and save it to codes array
            codesArray.add(child.key)
        }
        //Se il codice volontario si trova nell'array principale allora...
        if codesArray.contains(self.codvolontario.text!) {


            //creazione array per distribuzione sede
            let sedeconditionalRef = rootRef.child(self.codvolontario.text!).child("Sede")
            sedeconditionalRef.observe(.value) {(snapsede: DataSnapshot) in
                // This is empty array which will contain all the codes
                let sedeArray: NSMutableArray = []
                // Get all the children from snapshot you got back from Firebase
                let snapshotChildrensede = snapsede.children
                // Loop over all children (code) in Firebase
                while let childsede = snapshotChildrensede.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
                    // Get code node key and save it to codes array
                    sedeArray.add(childsede.key)


                }
            }
            print(sedeConditionalRef)
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueSchedaVolontario", sender: self)
        }
        else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Errore", message: "Codice volontario non valido", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    }

    //Torna indietro
    @IBAction func close() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

This is the second Swift file

```swift
//
//  SchedaVolontario.swift
//  Amesci
//
//  Created by Gianluca Caliendo on 06/07/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Amesci. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase

class SchedaVolontario: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var SedeEnte: UILabel!



    func changesedelabel()  {

        //

        }
    }


    @IBAction func close() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

### edit

i'm near the solution. I tried this solution and it doesn't give me error, but it doesn't return any result:

This is in the first Swift file:

```
    public func arraycontainer() {

        //creazione array per distribuzione sede
        let sederootRef = Database.database().reference()
        let sedeconditionalRef = sederootRef.child(self.codvolontario.text!).child("Sede")
        sedeconditionalRef.observe(.value) {(snapsede: DataSnapshot) in
            // This is empty array which will contain all the codes
            let sedeArray: NSMutableArray = []
            // Get all the children from snapshot you got back from Firebase
            let snapshotChildrensede = snapsede.children
            // Loop over all children (code) in Firebase
            while let childsede = snapshotChildrensede.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {
                // Get code node key and save it to codes array
                sedeArray.add(childsede.value!)
            }
    }
}
```

this is in the Second Swift file:

```
    override func performSelector(inBackground aSelector: Selector, with arg: Any?) {
   let array = AccessoTerzoLivello.arraycontainer
    self.SedeEnte.text = array as? String
}
```

### edit 2

First Swift file:

```
func PassCode(){
    let displayViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SchedaVolontario") as! SchedaVolontario
    displayViewController.sede = self.codvolontario.text
}
```

Second Swift file:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var SedeEnte: UILabel!

var sede: String?

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.SedeEnte.text = sede
print(sede!)

}
```

Comment: If you're getting the required node in first VC, why don't inject it in second VC before performing the segue?

Comment: u... are... a genius! let's try

Comment: I think It is better to create a model class so that you can update and reach your data everywhere.

Comment: Don't Forget that we are retrieving data from firebase, and for do this we need a function

Comment: In your first view, you are defining the root ref like this *let rootRef = Database.database().reference()* but in your second file, you are defining the root ref like this *let labelrootRef = Database.database().reference()* calling it labelrootRef which is confusing. Then in the second controller you are creating a reference to a child of a child. There's no way to know if any of that is correct as you've not included your Firebase structure (as text). I would add a few print statements and see if those paths are correct i.e *print(labelconditionalRef)*.

Comment: i'm near, see the edit

Comment: The code in your edit is unnecessary as the Sede node only has a value. So *let someValue = snapshot.value as! String* would assign *Universite degli...* to the someValue var. Also, in the future, please post your Firebase structure as TEXT, no images or links. Links break and images cannot be copied and pasted into an answer whereas text can.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are attempting to accomplish as well. I think you want to iterate over the SchedaVolontari node and get data from each child node? Perhaps the data from the Seda child node?

Comment: i want to change the label text of the Second VC as value of key "Sede" of this CodNode

Comment: i just want to do something like this: youtube.com/watch?v=2duc77R4Hqw the Problem is, how did he do?

Comment: The question and code is still very unclear. If you have a reference... *sederootRef.child("V2016040517").child("Sede")* and you observe that by .value, one, and only one item is returned in the snapshot: it's a string and will be Universite degli... . So if the code in the closure is *let myString = snapshot.value as! String* then myString will equal *Universite degli* which you can then use to update the label on your view. PLEASE include your Firebase structure as text, not an image.

Comment: @Jay ok, i edite, but i cold't write all cases, cause the database is too large... but i just wrote some different cases

Comment: There's obviously a misunderstanding of the code: This Firebase reference *sederootRef.child("V2016040517").child("Sede")* has ONE child, no more. That child is a single value of type String. Your code is trying to iterate over child snapshot nodes which don't exist. If you want the value at that node, the solution is *let myString = snapshot.value as! String*.

Comment: ok, but we have more UserID witch compare... how can i nest the ID in the sederootRef? (i repeat: the IDcode is provided by user tiping his id on a textfield)

Comment: The complete path should be:   ref.child("SchedaVolontari").child(self.codvolontario.text).child("Sede")   i found another Way to pass the codvolontario var to another viewcontroller, see the edit 2   the only Problem is that it scende me an error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ISTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" on Print line

Comment: Again, *.child(self.codvolontario.text)* is a specific user id followed by a child node of *.‌​child("Sede")*. When you put that together, it's a reference to a single node which has a value of a String. You can't iterate over that. The follow up comment is confusing as if the users enters their id code, like *V2016040517* then the reference is *sederootRef.child("V2016040517").child("Sede")* which is a reference to a string value. Are you trying to query for a node? Are you trying to iterate over multiple children? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: **VC1**: Insert IDCode on textfield then press Button.                      **VC2**: Display label with information of that user logged in.                  The Problem is: we have thousands of IDCodes on database, witch of that did selected the user? (So yes, i'm trying to query a specific node)

Comment: in this case, i want to display the value of the key "Sede" of the selected IDCode by using a label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I still fully understand the question but here's a possible answer.

Assume you have a Firebase structure like this

```
  "SchedaVolontari" : {
    "V2016040517" : {
      "CodiceVolontario" : "V2016040517",
      "Cognome" : "SANTORO",
      "DataFineServizio" : "09/01/2018",
      "DataInizioServizio" : "10/01/2017"
    }
    "V2016040518" : {
      "CodiceVolontario" : "V2016040518",
      "Cognome" : "CUSUMANO",
      "DataFineServizio" : "09/01/2018",
      "DataInizioServizio" : "10/01/2017"
    }
```

and in your app, a view is displayed asking for the user to enter their code. The user enters

```
V2016040518
```

with is the second entry in the above structure

The app then switches to a different view that shows the user details. Assuming the code is in place to switch views, we pass the code the user entered into the user detail via represtedObject or some such technique.

Then load the users details and print them to the console:

```
let user_code = self.representedObject as! String

let userRef = rootRef.child("SchedaVolontari").child(user_code)
userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
     let userDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
     let surname = userDict["Cognome"] as! String
     let endService = userDict["DataFineServizio"]  as! String
     let startService = userDict["DataInizioServizio"] as! String

     print("surname: \(cognome)  start: \(startService)  end: \(endService)")
})
```

then prints

```
surname: CUSUMANO  start: 10/01/2017  end: 09/01/2018
```

Comment: Oh my God!!! It works! thank you very very very much man!! (i Will pass this variabile in the other View controller by using global variabiles) Thank, thanks a lot!